# why is the output not from top to bottom C

Tags: c

my code looks 1:1 like this :       you may disregard the ft_strlen function

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_strlen(char *c)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(c[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}

int main() 
{
    char rockPaperScissores[] = "THIS IS rockPaperScissores^tm: ";
    int rps = ft_strlen(rockPaperScissores);
    
    printf("%d\n", rps);

    write(1, rockPaperScissores, rps);
    write(1, "LETS PLAY!!!\n", 13);

    for (int i = 51; i >= 49; i--)
    {
        write(1, &i , 1);
        write(1, "\n" , 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and my OUTPUT looks like this :

```
THIS IS rockPaperScissores^tm: LETS PLAY!!!
3
2
1
31
```

my question now being...why is the "31" as last in my output when it should have been the first.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: `printf` is buffered, `write` is not. Usually the `\n` is enough to flush the buffer in a line buffered environment but if you want to be sure use `fflush`.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", rps);` vane

Comment: Oh I see - it was buffered as Ninja says. Don't mix your input or output methods: they have different behaviours.

Comment: @Weather Vane, Use `prog | cat` to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stdio functions use buffered io. Writes to the underlying file descriptor only happen when the buffer becomes full or when the program exits.<sup>[1]</sup> `stdout` is also flushed when a LF is encountered if it's connected to a terminal.

In your case, it appears that `stdout` wasn't connected to a terminal. Since the buffer never filled up, it wrote its output to the underling file descriptor on exit.

---

1. Additionally, the buffer can be flushed explicitly using `fflush`. Also, it's possible to disable buffering for a handle. This is already done for `stderr`.